# Flutter SecretBox asking for MAC for AES-GCM-256

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt AES-256-GCM data. As far as I know MAC isn't required for GCM but SecretBox is giving me exception `SecretBox has wrong message authentication code (MAC)` when I specify `mac: Mac.empty`

Following is my code snippet for decryption

```
final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

final decryptedBody = await algorithm.decrypt(
      SecretBox(
        encryptedResponse,
        nonce: decryptionNonce,
        mac: Mac.empty,
      ),
      secretKey: key,
    );
```

Is there a way I can decrypt without using MAC? Because I'm not getting the MAC from the source of the ciphertext. The received ciphertext is `<nonce>.<ctext>`

> As far as I know MAC isn't required for GCM

I'm a beginner to cryptography so this statement might be incorrect, please correct it if wrong.

Comment: *...MAC isn't required for GCM...* [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) is authenticated encryption and uses a tag/MAC for authentication! *... I'm not getting the MAC from the source...* Note that libraries often append the tag to the ciphertext.

Comment: How can I extract it from the ciphertext? Is there any separator I can split the string with?

Comment: If `<ctext>` is a base64 or hex encoded string, you should decode it and try the last 16 bytes as tag (16 is the tag default length). Ultimately you have to ask this information (location, length etc.) from the encrypting side.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it thanks to @Topaco's comment.

The ciphertext is a combination of `<actualCipherText><MAC>`. The MAC is appended as the last 16 bytes of the ciphertext.

Below is my code snippet that works

```
var encryptedData = YOUR_DATA;

//Getting the last 16 bytes
var mac = encryptedData.sublist(encryptedData.length - 16);

//Separating the ciphertext from the mac
encryptedData = encryptedData.sublist(0, encryptedData.length - 16);

//Decrypting
final decryptedData = await algorithm.decrypt(
    SecretBox(
       encryptedData,
       nonce: decryptionNonce,
       mac: Mac(mac),
    ),
    secretKey: key,
);
```